# Bound on the probability of infinity norm of a Gaussian vector

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

I consider a random vector $X\in \mathbb{R}^N$ following a multivariate Gaussian distribution of mean zero and covariance matrix $\Sigma_X$ such that $\forall 1\le i \le N, (\Sigma_X)_{ii}=1$ (there are only 1's on the diagonal). I am interrested in the maximum of the absolute value of the elements of $X$ : $\lVert X \rVert_\infty = \max_{1\le n \le N} |X_n|$.

I have the intuition that the following inequality is true:
\begin{equation}\label{goal}
\forall K>0, \; \mathbb{P}(\lVert X \rVert_\infty \le K) \ge \mathbb{P}(\lVert Y \rVert_\infty \le K) \qquad \mathrm{where} \qquad Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_N)
\end{equation}
In other words, the probability of $\lVert X \rVert_\infty$ being smaller than $K$ is minimum in the case where all the elements of $X$ are iid centered normal variables.

I managed to prove this in the case $N=2$ by direct calculation of the above probability but the integrals get too complicated for bigger $N$. Does this result holds for $N>2$ and is there a proof ?

In the case that the result is not true, are there smaller classes of covariance matrices $\Sigma_X$ (for example Toeplitz matrices, or Toeplitz matrices with $1, \rho, \rho^2,\rho^3,\dots$ on the first line) for which the inequality holds ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some bibliographic research, I found that the inequality is indeed true.

It can be proven by successive application of theorem 2 of the following paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08776) with $t_1,\dots,t_n = K$ and $n_1=1$.